# Rails 3. How to setup a controller with custom params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I create a controller to manage account balance `BalanceController`. It's supposed to use data from the Invoices and Expenses table. So I added one action to the BalanceController called `account_balance`. But I need to add a month and year param to generate a balance report.

This doesn't seem to work on routes.rb

```
get 'balance/account_balance/:month' => 'balance#account_balance/:month'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get 'balance/account_balance/:month' => 'balance#account_balance'`

The string is just a controller/action combo.

Going to /balance/account_balance/march would then route to the `account_balance` action of the `balance` controller and `params[:month]` would be set to 'march'.